# Grid Datasource in WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Im really new to WP8... and I still do to understand some mechanism i used to face off when i developed in aspnet... For Example, datasource, databind,...

I do not understand how to visualize some element in a grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Loaded="ContentPanel_Loaded">

      <TextBlock x:Name="xx" .../>  
</Grid>
```

I just want to repeat the textblock n times... in this moment the only way i manage to do this, is doing somenthing like this

```
foreach (....)
{
     TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
     tb.Text = p.Name;

     ContentPanel.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

But i suppose this is not the right way... any suggestion? Thanx

Comment: ItemsControl is the closest of ASP.NET's Repeater, it's a good place to start. Set the TextBlock in the DataTemplate, set the ItemsSource, and you're good to go

Comment: There are number of ways but for repeated controls Ill give you the one of best option wait for a sec :)

Comment: @Kookiz... I cant find ItemSource property in the Grid!! And another thing, plz... which is the raised event when ItemSource is set (something like OnItemDataBound or OnRowDataBound in repeater/gridview asp.net) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="NameList">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200"/>

           </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

cs

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using StackOverFlowTestApp.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace StackOverFlowTestApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask;
        private List<int> listMinutes = new List<int>();
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> list = new List<User>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                User user = new User();
                user.name = "Anobik"+i;
                list.Add(user);
            }
            NameList.ItemsSource = list;
        }


    }


    public class User {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Try with it the simplest way. but actually the concept of binding extends to MVVM so you can read from the article

[MVVM windows phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: mmm... In grid the ItemSource property do not exists... Im trying with DataContext item but nothing append
    
    `ContentPanel.DataContext = myList`

myList contain a property called Name.. This my xaml:

     `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="White">     </TextBlock>`

Comment: Actually if you are going for a list of items ie multiple numbers then it is advised to use ListBox. If you want to add a multiple number of textbox then at ay moment you need to either write code for 10 with data(static) or create a loop to add 10 items. But for convenience to bind data dynamically listboxes and MVVM are used. The same way i have put {Binding  Path=Name} and added a class with property name you can do the same. Use DataContext property in MVVM in that case.

Comment: Ok I have done a MVVM project... with Listbox is perfect.. works everything perfectly... with Grid and DataContext set, does not work... Im using same Model and same ViewModel.. just 2 different Views... But Im thinking about your consideration "Actually if you are going for a list of items ie multiple numbers then it is advised to use ListBox".. You mean that if I want a grid layout I should go a vertical listbox that contain an horizontal list box as item template (For example, Photo app look like a grid not a list)

Comment: Resolved with a ListBox inside a Grid... On Listbox i set the property `Source={Binding}`... then i set the Grid property `DataContext=MyDataSource`.... Actually my data source will be set on Listbox not on Grid...  I do not understand why i cannot use Grid without Listbox but it could make sense...

Comment: Only reason I asked you to use a List box is because it is a standard control for rendering a number of items. On the other hand you need to loop to insert items inside grid. While a list box can make things easy for you. DataContext can be even set on the entire page if you wish to but list box databing -- Source={Binding} this is essential.

Comment: Hi Ciccio wrt @I do not understand why i cannot use Grid -- Only way I asked you to use list box because it will cause a rendering issue maybe a hang or something suppose 500 elements are to be loaded. While this is handled internally by the list box. :)